# alignments in this commutative diagram

Tags: tikz-cd

I've got this diagram:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
 ... \arrow[r,""] 
& G_{n+1} \arrow[r, "\partial_{n+1}"] \arrow[rd, "f\circ \partial{n+1}"']
& G_{n} \arrow[rd, "g\circ \partial_{n}"'] \arrow[r,"\partial{n}"] \arrow[d,"f"'] 
& G_{n-1} \arrow[r,"\partial_{n-1}"]  \arrow[d, "g"'] \arrow[rd, "f'\circ\partial_{n-1}"']
& G_{n-2} \arrow[r, "\partial{n-2}"] \arrow[d, "f'"'] \arrow[rd]
& ...\\  
& 
& M  & M 
& M &...
\end{tikzcd}
```

the problem is: when it prints `f'\circ\partial_{n-1}` it overlaps a downarrow 
simply because that function composition is too much spaced from it's `rd` arrow.
How do I resolve?

Comment: How do you want to resolve it, or are you asking for a suggestion? If you are asking for a suggestion, then unfortunately, this is opinion-based.

Comment: well, by resolving I mean how to avoid the overleapping between the function and the downarrow

Comment: Sure, but please provide a sketch of how you want it to look like

Comment: The answer here down just talks for me! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd increase the row and column separation, besides moving the labels nearer to the diagonal arrows.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large,row sep=huge]
 \dots \arrow[r,""] 
& G_{n+1} \arrow[r, "\partial_{n+1}"] \arrow[rd, "f\circ \partial_{n+1}\!\!"']
& G_{n} \arrow[rd, "g\circ \partial_{n}\!\!"'] \arrow[r,"\partial{n}"] \arrow[d,"f"'] 
& G_{n-1} \arrow[r,"\partial_{n-1}"]  \arrow[d, "g"'] \arrow[rd, "f'\circ\partial_{n-1}\!\!\!\!"']
& G_{n-2} \arrow[r, "\partial{n-2}"] \arrow[d, "f'"'] \arrow[rd]
& \dots \\  
& 
& M  & M 
& M & \dots
\end{tikzcd} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably best is to increase the row and column spacing, is in egreg's solution.  But you can alternatively provide some adjustment to spacing of labels by writing `tikz` options after them, e.g. `yshift=.5ex` or `shift={(.5em,.5ex)}`, and you can move a given column right by replacing `&` by `&[2em]` in the first row.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
  \cdots \arrow[r,""]
  & G_{n+1}
  \arrow[r, "\partial_{n+1}"]
  \arrow[rd, "f\circ \partial{n+1}"' yshift=.5ex]
  & G_{n}
  \arrow[rd, "g\circ \partial_{n}"' yshift=.5ex]
  \arrow[r,"\partial{n}"]
  \arrow[d,"f"']
  & G_{n-1}
  \arrow[r,"\partial_{n-1}"]
  \arrow[d, "g"']
  \arrow[rd, "f'\circ\partial_{n-1}"' shift={(.5em,.5ex)}]
  &[2em] G_{n-2}
  \arrow[r, "\partial{n-2}"]
  \arrow[d, "f'"']
  \arrow[rd]
  & \cdots\\
  & & M & M & M &\cdots
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```